# Scaling of mesh world-relative

Tags: matrix, three.js

In Object3D contains a mesh
Object3D has an arbitrary scaling
Mesh has an arbitrary rotation. So my mesh is scaled relative to world coordinates.

But when I detach my mesh in the scene (for example, with the aid of THREE.SceneUtils.detach (mesh, obj3d, scene) I get an incorrect result, the mesh is scaled only locally.

I tried to change the geometry of the mesh, but still get an incorrect result:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ni55aN/VsWb9/3426/

```
 var euler = new THREE.Euler(-mesh.rotation.x,-mesh.rotation.y,-mesh.rotation.z);

 mesh.geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationFromEuler(mesh.rotation));        
 mesh.geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale( 
                         obj.scale.x, 
                         obj.scale.y,  
                         obj.scale.z
                     ));
 mesh.geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationFromEuler(euler));        
 mesh.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate=true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized what was my mistake.
It was necessary to apply getInverse of my first matrix instead .makeRotationFromEuler with negative values

```
    var firstMatrix=new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationFromEuler(mesh.rotation);
    var inverseMatrix=new THREE.Matrix4().getInverse(firstMatrix);

   mesh.geometry.applyMatrix(firstMatrix);        
        mesh.geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale( 
                                     obj.scale.x, 
                                     obj.scale.y,  
                                     obj.scale.z
                                 ));
    mesh.geometry.applyMatrix(inverseMatrix);   

     mesh.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate=true;
```